# ServiceM8 - Calling the job material list via API (Python/Zapier)

Tags: python, automation, zapier, servicem8

I have a zapier integration in servicem8 that is meant to be calling the job materials list from servicem8 when a job gets assigned to a specific que. I can trigger the action when the job lands in the que and pass it along to my python script which is meant to provide a line item array of all the materials filtered by the uuid of the job which triggered my zap. Once I have a list of all materials for a job I can trigger other action steps such as automatic ordering, drafting quotes etc...

The materials list is within the quotes and invoicing tab (see picture)

My trigger step in zapier triggers whenever a job hits the specified que. The record doesn't return a list of materials associated with the job so I believe I need a code step to pull that list from ServiceM8.
I've written a script in python.

```
job_uuid = input_data['jobuuid']

url = f"https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/jobmaterial.json?%24filter=job_uuid eq {job_uuid}"

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Basic MY_API_KEY"
}

all_materials = []

while url:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        materials_data = response.json()
        all_materials.extend(materials_data)
        url = response.links.get('next', {}).get('url')
    else:
        return {
            "error": f"Request failed with status code: {response.status_code}"
        }
return.all_materials
```

when I execute that code in zapier, it only returns the first line-item from the materials list. I incorporated the "while" loop incase servicem8 pagnates only 1 result per page... still only a single line item is returned.

Anyone worked with this stuff before have any ideas how to pull the full list of materials from ServiceM8?

thanks!

`